# mySQL Query Error in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have this code:

```
add_action( 'delete_post', 'my_delete_function' );
 function my_delete_function($post_id) { 
    global $wpdb;
    $achievement = get_the_category($post_id); 
    $h = $achievement[0]->cat_ID; 
    $s = ''.str_replace('"', '', $h);
    $p = var_dump(htmlentities($s));
   $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO ".$wpdb->prefix."votes (post, votes, guests, usersinks, guestsinks) VALUES('', ".$p.", '', '', '') ") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

mySQL keeps throwing this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '', '', '')' at line 1
```

Ive ran the same query in phpMyAdmin, replacing the php vars with values and it works fine

Additionally, ive made sure the the value of $s is just a number by using the echo function on a blank page.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Add a `var_dump($s);` right before the last line to check what you're outputting. If it contains HTML, use `var_dump(htmlentities($s));`

Comment: Can you show the full final query?

Comment: Check that your single quotes are actually single quotes and not backquotes. Also replace .$s. with .(int)$s. just to make sure.

Comment: @AramKocharyan - I tried var dump but i got this error: string(0) "" You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '', '', '')' at line 1

Comment: @DickLaurent- this is the full query. The code i have given is wrapped around a wordpress action. Ill update the above code to matxh my entire function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe 
`$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO ".$wpdb->prefix."votes (post, votes, guests, usersinks, guestsinks) VALUES('', '".$s."', '', '', '') ") or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the last error and last query you can use this properties of **$wpdb** object:

```
$wpdb->last_error
```

will show you the last error, if you got one.

```
$wpdb->last_query
```

will assist you with showing the last query (where the error occurred)

I hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the $s is empty and the SQL query ends up looking like this:

```
VALUES('', , '', '', '')
```

Why are you doing

```
$s = str_replace('"', '', $h);
```

Is it actually possible that the int contains an "? This is not nice. But I'd eventually do this

```
$s = (int)str_replace('"', '', $h);
```

to ensure that the variable is an int - no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
global $wpdb;
$achievement = get_the_category($post_id); 
$h = $achievement[0]->cat_ID; 
$s = str_replace('"', '', $h);
$wpdb->query("
    INSERT INTO ".$wpdb->prefix."votes (votes) 
    VALUES ('".$s."');") or die(mysql_error());
```

If that doesn't work then you are probably leaving blank fields that require a value.